# Make test script TimeZone agnostic

Tags: java, timezone

I have a script (Java) that sends an order to a component in a different timezone:

```
final Date now = new Date();
long effectiveTime = now.getTime();
long expireTime = DateUtils.addMinutes(now, 2).getTime();

order.setEffectiveTime(effectiveTime)
     .setExpireTime(expireTime)
     .send();
```

Now, since I'm in GMT+1 and component is GMT-0 (London), I verify as follows:

```
// Shift 1 hour
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
final String expectedEffectiveTime =  f.format(DateUtils.addHours(now,-1));
final String expectedExpireTime = f.format(DateUtils.addHours(DateUtils.addMinutes(now, 2),-1));

String logString = getLogString(order);

Assert.assertTrue(logString.contains(expectedEffectiveTimeText));
Assert.assertTrue(logString.contains(expectedExpireTimeText));
```

The above works, but only if you run the script in my Timezone. Running the script in any other timezone will, of course fail. Is there an elegant way to write the script in a timezone-agnostic way with the *only constant being that the expected output will be adjusted to GMT-0*?

Comment: Stop using `Date`. It has no notion of time zone. Use a `ZonedDateTime` instead (if you're on Java 8), or the threeten or jodatime equivalent otherwise.

Comment: Also, stop using `SimpleDateFormat`. These are really, really awful classes that only still exist for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: "component is GMT-0 (London)" London's timezone is not GMT-0. It's `Europe/London`. (Right now, London has a 1 hour offset from GMT, because it's summer).

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. Thanks to them I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andy Turner's comments I found the solution using Java 8:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(),ZoneId.systemDefault()); 

// need longs because setter methods accept either Date or long 
long effectiveTime = now.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
long expireTime = now.plusMinutes(2).toInstant().toEpochMilli();


// send 
order.setEffectiveTime(effectiveTime)
      .setExpireTime(expireTime)
      .send();


// Verify
String expectedEffectiveTime = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
                                  .toLocalTime().toString();

String expectedExpireTime = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
                               .plusMinutes(2).toLocalTime().toString();


String logString = getLogString(order);
Assert.assertTrue(logString.contains(expectedEffectiveTimeText));
Assert.assertTrue(logString.contains(expectedExpireTimeText));
```